# SSH - How to delete all .htaccess files inside the wp-content folders?

Tags: ssh

I have thousands of .htaccess files added by malware, I need to login via SSH and delete them, but only when they are inside wp-content folder, outside this folder they need to stay.

What's the cmd please?

Answer (score 0):

Note this is for Python
Try This:

```
import os

file_type = input("Enter file type: ")
folder_path = input("Enter folder path: ")

filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for file in files:
        #append the file name to the list
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))

#print all the file names
for name in filelist:
    delete_file = str(name)
    if delete_file.endswith(file_type):
        os.remove(delete_file)
        print("File deleted successfully.")
        break
else:
    print("No files found.")
```